# How to index field as single value?

Tags: 7, database, search

I use `Search API`, `Search API Database` and `FacetAPI`to create custom search. And there are mistakes in facets when it displays field with hyphens. For example, there is a text field "city" with value of "Rostov-na-Donu" (the name of the city in Russia). Facets show me three values: Rostov, na, Donu. But I want only one value for this field and it should be entire field content.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to index the field as "string", not "fulltext".